# LARAVEL - Pass variable from controller to view

Tags: php, laravel

I want to show my posts on the homepage just under my form.
I can already add post to my DB.

Now I just get Undefined variable if I try to use this variable in my view page.

Route =

```
Route::resource('posts', 'PostController');
```

Controller =

```
public function show()
{
    $posts = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->get();

    return view('/home', [
        'posts' => $posts
    ]);
}
```

View

```
@if (count($posts) > 0)
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            Posts
        </div>

        <div class="panel-body">
            <table class="table table-striped task-table">

                <!-- Table Headings -->
                <thead>
                <th>Posts</th>
                <th>&nbsp;</th>
                </thead>

                <!-- Table Body -->
                <tbody>
                @foreach ($posts as $post)
                    <tr>
                        <!-- Post Name -->
                        <td class="table-text">
                            <div>{{ $post->description }}</div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: Try to print $posts in your controller to see what it shows. Also in your view, add a if condition if(isset($posts)) before looping through it. And, post your view code here if you need more help

Comment: show your view code for access the variable.

Comment: Where do you get an error? On the webpage? In the logfile?

Comment: on the webpage.

Comment: View code is available now!

Comment: That "/" is to much. Try only `view('home', ...`

Comment: please write the path, where your view placed

Comment: @mikrafizik just in the view folder..

Answer (score 2):

The right way is using Route::resources() only for REST (just my opinion). Try to create a new Route like

```
Route::get('hello-there', [
    'as' => 'front.index',
    'uses' => 'PostController@index',
]);
```

Now u can get access to your action by: "wwww.mydomain.com/hell-there
Next step - make action named "index" if it is list.

```
public function index()
{
    return view('home', [
        'posts' => Post::orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->get(),
    ])
}
```

U need blade view file in below directory named "home.blade.php":

`application_path/resources/`

Your blade file looks correct. Good luck mate.

Comment: Thanks mate, Route::resources() was the way I would like to do first but this works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public function show()
{
    $posts = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->get();

    return view('home', [
        'posts' => $posts
    ]);
}
```

and show us your blade view, what the path and name?

Comment: and show us your blade view, what the path and name?

Comment: lol, disliked, that is true answer, u have an issue with name of your view

Answer (score 0):

you could try to use:

return view('/home', compact('posts));

this works for me.